# Breaking string into sets of substrings using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c, substr, nvl

I have a column that stores a string representing a food order. The string goes as
 "102*4;109*3;101*2".
 Here the 3 digit represents the item code separated by '*' with the quantity while ';' acts as a separator among the item.
I want to find a way separate the item code and quantity using SQL. I have done it before but used front end programming to separate it before entering the database

Comment: What you need is `split_string` with three parameters: input string, delimiter and separator. Unfortunately, the last time I checked Oracle 12C such function did not exist, so I wrote my own (change work place so I cannot share it here). In any case, it is a simple function to implement.

Comment: String manipulation in SQL is nearly always my last choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12C then you can use regular expression to achieve your result.
for example:-

```
    create table food_order (order_no number, food_order varchar2(500));

    insert into food_order values (1001,'102*4;109*3;101*2');
    insert into food_order values (1002,'103*3;108*5;101*3');
    insert into food_order values (1003,'106*4;107*3;109*2');
    insert into food_order values (1004,'106*4;105*3;101*7');

    select * from food_order;

Output:-

ORDER_NO    FOOD_ORDER
1001    102*4;109*3;101*2
1002    103*3;108*5;101*3
1003    106*4;107*3;109*2
1004    106*4;105*3;101*7
```

Now try the below query:-

```
    SELECT order_no,
     regexp_substr(food_order,'[^*]+', 1,1) AS"ORDER_ID",
     regexp_substr(food_order,'[^*]+', 1,2) AS"QUANTITY"
      FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT order_no,
        regexp_substr(food_order,'[^;]+', 1, level) AS"FOOD_ORDER"
      FROM food_order
     CONNECT BY regexp_substr(food_order, '[^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
    ) temp order by order_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select column name from table_name where regexp_replace(column_name,[^{A-Z})])
  Union all
Select column name from tablename where 
Regexp_replace(values,'/d');
```